# Java take code in params like: new ActionListener({ "code here" })

Tags: java, parameters

i would like to know how to take code in params of a object (just like an actionlistener takes code in brackets {} ) **AND** how to trigger it
I would like to know if possible, and if not if its possible by using the actionlistener or something else thats already in java,
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [Anonymous Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), from the tutorial -

> The anonymous class expression consists of the following:
>
> 1. The new operator
> 2. The name of an interface to implement or a class to extend. In this example, the anonymous class is implementing the interface HelloWorld.
> 3. Parentheses that contain the arguments to a constructor, just like a normal class instance creation expression. Note: When you implement an interface, there is no constructor, so you use an empty pair of parentheses, as in this example.
> 4. A body, which is a class declaration body. More specifically, in the body, method declarations are allowed but statements are not.

Finally, your provided syntax is not correct - it's closer to

```
JButton btn;
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Called.
  }
});
```

Comment: It's much nicer in Java 8.

Comment: Oh, is this really a Java 8 lambda question?

Comment: Hard to tell from the question. It was just an observation on your answer.

Comment: Im not looking to put an actionlistener on some swing object, im looking how to give code in params from a class of your own